# Как написать код, работающий на GCC и VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

Известно, что оба компиля не дружат между собой, и один код, работающий с одним из них, не будет компилиться на другом, если в нём присутствуют специфические расширения языка свойственные каждому из компиляторов.

Есть ли такой подход, при котором написанный код будет собираться с обоими компиляторами?

Comment: Есть! Называется - **СТАНДАРТ**...

Comment: Так не используйте эксклюзивные штучки, а только стандартные и не будет проблем.

Comment: @xt1zer Проблема не в платформе, а в том, что вы используете собственные расширения языка компиляторами. Кроме того, любой из этих компиляторов может содержать баги. Поэтому в каждом отдельном случае надо рассматривать причину возникновения "разногласия" между компиляторами.

Comment: Кстати, а что вы понимаете под "платформой" в данном контексте? А то даже интересно - как вы себе это представляете...

Comment: Путем правильно расставленных дефайнов: `if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)` и `if defined(_MSC_VER)`

Comment: @zed Мне сложно определить является ли та или иная функция собственной для данного компилятора. Я бью в гугл нужную хрень и смотрю решение. Само собой, не везде они совпадают и по списку параметров, и по возвращаемому типу и т.п. Стояли бы в универе GCC на компах, я бы и не парился с этой темой

Comment: Ну так если "бить хрень", то хрень в ответ и получится. **Учить** нужно язык. И не "хрень бить", а выяснять, какие **стандартные** функции имеются. Забавно, но вы же хотите не решения своего вопроса (который и не задали), а подтверждения вашей правоты, в которой сами сомневаетесь. И не зря сомневаетесь, кстати :)

Comment: @Harry Звучит просто, но мысль, в общем, ясна. Учить язык. А значит открывать интернет исключительно для поиска информации по интересующим функциям (если таковые существуют в стандартных заголовках C++). А это не может означать, что, по большей части, порталы, вроде этой же StackOverflow, будет вреден в ходе учения?

Comment: @xt1zer, для продолжения в конструктивном ключе, приведите в вопросе код который собирается в gcc и не собирается в vc++. Вам дадут **конкретные рекомендации и предложат решение**

Comment: Как раз на SO вреден не будет - потому что когда тут задают вопрос по **языку** - решение будет предложено в рамках языка, а не конкретного компилятора. Ну, в 95% случаев :)

Comment: Включите для своего компилятора максимально строгие ошибки. Для GCC это `-std=c++?? -pedantic-errors` - с такими флажками он пропускает минимум непереносимого кода. *"Известно, что оба компиля не дружат между собой"* Последнее время MS взялся за ум и за новые стандарты, так что с новым MSVC проблем может быть совсем немного.